# Excel database - formula multiplication exchange rate by date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, rate

I am creating some accounting papers and I need multiplicate USD exchange rate with our currency by date. I tried everything, but I don't know how to do it.. 
Here is example:

```
DATE       |    USD  | CZK

1.1.2018 | 2$ |  USD Price * CZK Price by same date

2.2.2018 | 2$ |  USD Price * CZK Price by same date


EXCHANGE RATE

1.1.2018 | 22

2.2.2018 | 23
```

(It means that price on 1.1 will be 44CZK and 2.2 will be 46CZK)

And this I need do for every day in year. 
So hand writing isn't possible. I need some formula for it.
Can you help me please? I know that it can be by vlookup and If..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can muliply with the exchange rate in your cell while doing the lookup at the same time, so in Cell `C2`:

```
=B2*(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$3,2,FALSE))
```

---

I.e. `VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$3,2,FALSE)` will give you the exchange rate,

`A2`: Lookup value, the date in our case.

`$E$2:$F$3`: Where we can find the date in your "search area". Notice that the date we search for, needs to be in the first column of our "search area".

`2`: In our "search area", from which column number should we return our return number/value. In our case our "search area" is two column, where we want the result to be return from the 2nd column of column E and F.

`FALSE`: Search for exact match.

When the exchange rate is found we mulptiply it with the dollar amount, i.e. `B2 * Vlookup()` :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation, you are great! I used it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use INDEX with MATCH to achieve this as well and wrap in IFERROR in case a match for the "date" string is not found in the lookup column. If a match is found in the lookup column E, for the "date" string in column A the number returned for the match is passed as a row number argument for Index on column F which returns to rate in the same row as the match was found. This is then multiplied by column B.

You would alter the ranges $F$2:$F$3 and $E$2:$E$3 to encompass all your actual rows in those columns.

In B2 and drag down

```
=IFERROR(B2*INDEX($F$2:$F$3,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$3,0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you are great!